# Left join, ISNULL, IFNULL don't work

Tags: sql, left-join, isnull

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblflash` (
  `FID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FID`)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcount` (
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SID` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `FID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `elaspedTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)


$sqldate1 =
    "SELECT distinct tblflash.FID, tblflash.fname, IFNULL(sum(tblcount.elaspedTime),0)
    FROM tblflash 
    left outer JOIN tblcount 
    ON tblflash.FID = tblcount.FID 
    WHERE tblcount.SID='".$_SESSION['SID']."'
    ORDER BY tblflash.FID";
```

let's say there are 10 rows in tblflash has 10 rows and  5 rows in tblcount. 
the record shown shows in 5 rows only. I would like to show all the fname with no duplication, and if null set to 0.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE tblcount.SID='".$_SESSION['SID']."'` is making the query act as an `INNER JOIN` - you need to add `or tblcount.SID IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` condition is applied to the result of the join, *not* specifically to `tblcount` rows. And the join returns NULLs in all `tblcount` columns when there's no match between the two tables. As a result, `NULL = 'whatever'` *doesn't* evaluate to `true` and the row isn't returned.

Either add `OR tblcount.SID IS NULL` to WHERE as [@cjk has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110276/297408) or make the WHERE condition part of the ON clause, like this:

```
$sqldate1 =
    "SELECT distinct tblflash.FID, tblflash.fname, IFNULL(sum(tblcount.elaspedTime),0)
    FROM tblflash 
    left outer JOIN tblcount 
    ON tblflash.FID = tblcount.FID 
    AND tblcount.SID='".$_SESSION['SID']."'
    ORDER BY tblflash.FID";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no data for `SID` in `tblcount` for other 5 rows